# Stable MSN messenger for mac?

Tags: macos, instant-messaging, adium, windows-live-messenger

I use Adium in my mac as a client for MSN messenger. (I have also tried the "official" live messenger for mac for a while but it had even worse issues than what I am experiencing with Adium).

Everything works fine for the first 5-10 minutes, perhaps until the first automatic "away", then suddenly any message I send is followed by a dozen or so messages saying:

*"Message could not be sent because a connection error occurred:"*

and

*Message may have not been sent because a timeout occurred:*

If I send a few messages, they usually eventually arrive (all at once) after a long delay.

Windows machines on the same network running live messenger work fine.

Any ideas why this might be, or suggestions for a client that might work when both Adium and Microsofts own messenger for mac seem to disconnect?

Update: I added a google talk account to the same Audium install and it continues to work even when the MSN account disconnects. So the issue is only for the MSN protocol. Unfortunately I can't force all my contacts to swith accounts, so I still want to solve this.

The latest audium beta has the same issue, as does the latest MSN messenger beta. Am I really the only one with this problem? Nobody out there chatting over MSN on their macs?

Comment: How are you connected?  Wirelessly?  Also, what version of Mac do you have?  I know that some Mac models used to run into IM issues when the machine was on a wireless network.

Comment: Wired or wirelessly I have the same issue, also from different networks and ISPs.

Answer (score 1):

Give the [Adium Beta](http://beta.adium.im/) a try. Despite its beta label, it's quite stable. I've been using it for months now.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [aMSN](http://www.amsn-project.net/).

Comment: Thanks, I tried it but it has the same problem as Adium and Messenger. I guess it's not related to the client.